# How to Inner JOIN Table A+B and reference TABLE A to multiple other tables

Tags: mysql

Im currently and successfully doing a OUTER JOIN between TABLE A + B with the following:

```
SELECT * FROM player_img
  LEFT OUTER JOIN user_play
  ON player_img.player_img_id = user_play.user_play_entry_player_img_id
  AND user_play.user_play_uid = 1
  WHERE player_img.player_img_id IS null
```

This gives me all results from TABLE A that doesn't have any reference from TABLE B with `user_play_uid = 1`

In TABLE A, I have attributes that reference to other tables - Im looking to query out these fields also. A quick example of some table references:

```
TABLE_A:
player_img_id (unique key)
player_img_player_id (reference to: TABLE_C "player_id")
player_img_category_id (reference to: TABLE_D "category_id")

TABLE_B:
user_play_entry_player_img_id (reference to TABLE_A: "player_img_id")
user_play_uid (reference to table with user.id)

TABLE_C:
player_id (unique key)
player_country (reference to table with country.id)
player_league (reference to table with league.id)

TABLE_D:
category_id (unique key)
```

**Figured I could do something along the way of the following (which ofcourse doesnt work at all)**:

```
SELECT u . * , up . * , pi . * , p . * , c . *
  FROM user u, user_play up, player_img pi, player p, country c
  LEFT OUTER JOIN up
  ON pi.player_img_id = up.user_play_entry_player_img_id
  WHERE pi.player_img_id IS null
  AND up.user_play_uid = $this->user_id
  AND pi.player_img_category_id = $this->category_id
  AND pi.player_img_player_id = p.player_id
  AND p.player_country = c.country_id
```

Any suggestions on how I combine my OUTER JOIN with reference lookup tables across?

**EDIT:
Current attempt with below suggestions - query is running but no results showing - ideas?:/**

```
SELECT u . * , up . * , pi . * , p . * , c . *
  FROM user u
  INNER JOIN player_img pi
  ON pi.player_img_category_id  = 3
  INNER JOIN player p
  ON pi.player_img_player_id    = p.player_id
  INNER JOIN country c
  ON p.player_country           = c.country_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN user_play up
  ON pi.player_img_id = up.user_play_entry_player_img_id
  WHERE pi.player_img_id IS null
  AND up.user_play_uid      != 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the ANSI-92 `JOIN` syntax instead of the old syntax you are using:

```
SELECT u . * , up . * , pi . * , p . * , c . *
FROM user u
INNER JOIN player_img     pi ON ...
INNER JOIN player          p ON pi.player_img_player_id = p.player_id
INNER JOIN country         c ON p.player_country        = c.country_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_play up ON pi.player_img_id    = up.user_play_entry_player_img_id
WHERE pi.player_img_id IS null
  AND up.user_play_uid = $this->user_id
```

Things to note:

- There is no condition in your query to how to `JOIN` with the table `player_img pi` with other tables.
- The condition `AND up.user_play_uid = $this->user_id` might remove the unmcatched rows coming because of the `LEFT JOIN` in this case you might need to move that condition into a subquery instead of `LEFT OUTER JOIN` that table directly.

Comment: Hi Mahmoud,

I tried applying your suggestion (you can see my edit) - however no results are showing. Im not sure if this could be a result of what you point out in your last comment - im a bit unsure where to move it like you suggest? Am I missing something in my test query ?

Comment: @user1231561 May be there are no rows that satisfy these conditions, try to remove the conditions and test it if it work fine, and for the table `INNER JOIN player_img pi
  ON pi.player_img_category_id  = 3` how it is relate to other tables by which columns?